# Having been built vs being built

Tags: present-perfect

1. This bridge,  which has been built for nine years,  will be the longest in our city.
   ( Intended meaning: the bridge is yet to finish; people have worked on it for nine years)
2. This bridge, __ (being built/built/ having been built ) for nine years will be the longest in our city.

I made the sentence (1).  I want to know  which of (2) is the correct non-finite form corresponding to the relative clause.

Comment: Sentence #1 is grammatically incorrect.  "Has been built" means that it is now complete, so "for nine years" doesn't match that.  I think you mean "the bridge has been *being built* for nine years", but that is a clumsy [present perfect progressive passive](https://parentingpatch.com/present-perfect-progressive-passive-english-verbs/) construction, so people would usually say "this bridge has been under construction for nine years".

Comment: This bridge is being built right now.  versus: The bridge has been being built for 9 years.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that sentence (1) is incorrect,  and it should be "which has been built for nine years"--  is there a way to reduce the relative clause?

Comment: no, "which has been built for nine years" is incorrect, because there "built" would be an adjective meaning "completed in its construction." That sentence means that the bridge's construction has been completed 9 years ago, which isn't what you intended.

Comment: what has been suggested is "which has been *being built* for nine years," which means that it was *in the process of being built* for nine years, and the usual, less-wordy way of saying that would be "which was *under construction* for nine years"

Comment: SO sorry！   I copied from OP, and was going to insert "being"  but,  I don't know, something went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sentence 1, as others have pointed out in comments, "This bridge, which has been being built..." is correct, but very clumsy (anything with "been being" sounds clumsy). The suggestions of using "under construction" are correct, but that doesn't address the grammar question in cases where there isn't a simpler alternate phrasing.

> This gold reserve, *which has been being amassed* for nine years, will be the largest in the world when complete

This too is correct and terribly clumsy. A native speaker would stumble over the words while saying them. It can only be fixed by removing the passive voice:

> ...*which we have been amassing* for nine years...

Sentence 2 is impossible to complete correctly. It can be *grammatically* completed like this:

> The bridge, *having been being built* for nine years, will be the longest in the city

but the meaning is wrong. Replacing the relative clause with an "-ing" clause introduces the unintended meaning of *causation*, in other words, this sentence means the bridge will be the longest in the city *because* it's been under construction for nine years.